# UITests Disabled in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

My UITests are suddenly greyed out in XCode's test pane.  (See image below.)  As a result, they don't run when I choose Product -> Test.  Only the Unit Tests Run (which are not greyed out.)

Despite them being greyed out, I can ctrl-click on each line item in the UITests and run it successfully.

Any idea what configuration is causing this to be greyed out?  How can I reverse it?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Somehow the UITest target got removed from the scheme for the main target.  To fix this, select the main target, then go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.  Then in the dialog below, choose the Test pane, and add the UITest target by hitting the + button at the bottom of the panel.

[image]